# flatten arrays with different length and values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in a table in Snowflake that has arrays in it. I'd like to flatten these arrays so that each one get it's own column. But wait! The arrays in these rows have different lengths, and/or different values!

Say I have

| fruit_array |
| --- |
| [ "Apple", "Peach", "Plum" ] |
| [ "Apple", "Chicken"] |

How do I end up with a table with columns like:

| Apple | Peach | Plum | Chicken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True |  |
| True |  |  | True |

Comment: what have you tried, if any? what part you did get stuck?

Comment: I found the max number of elements in the col of arrays, and then for each element, I made a new row in the select statement and accessed the values by index. So since the longest array has 16 items, there's 16 rows of SQL to pull out the items. Ooops. I guess I need to sort first. Ugh.